# Flutter how open an url in browser with cookies

Tags: flutter, cookies, browser, url-launcher

I am using url_launcher package to open a link with browser in my flutter app.
but how can I send some cookies too? if url_launcher can't do this, is there any other packages or ways to do this task?
my scenario is get cookies form WebView which opened in my flutter app, and when user wants to confirm the basket navigate him/her to browser for purchase and I need to send the session and cookies to the browser too.

Comment: I do not think that is possible. Browser and your app are completely different. Is there any reason to do not to use web view instead of web-browser? Returning from the webview is much easier for the same reason.

Comment: I think it makes users won't trust for payment or login on webview, because as you know it's not secure for user secrets.

Comment: Actually, I didn't see any app that opens a browser for payment flow, all flows, as I see, are done inside webview, without leaving the app. Even for social media log in, the most of time a webview is being opened.